# How to send automatically a newsletter when a new product is added?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, newsletter

my client wants to send automatically a newsletter every time a new product is added. The newsletter should be segmented by categories and stores, so the user has to choose which would subscribe. 
Is there any plugin/module as starting point?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply wanting to add a link to the product into the newsletter then you can add a new newsletter template, then insert into this template using the cms widget "Catalog Product Link" you can add a link to a product. This is the same as adding a link to a product via a cms page or block.

If you are looking at sending a product list then I would suggest looking into how the widget "Catalog New Products List" works. You could extend this to take a list of product ids that need to be included in your list.

A nice example is the block Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Random here is just makes a list of products randomly but you could add a products ids attribute and then create your own _getProductCollection

or follow this article

```
https://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/newsletter
```

Comment: i'm sorry, I missed the point. the newsletter should be automatic whenever a new product is added. the module/plugin should filter subscribers by stores and categories. thanks

Comment: then you can use extension or third party like mail chimp

Comment: will it send automatically new products?

Comment: I used the new product widget to create a newsletter template, the I developed a cron module to add programmatically it to the newsletter queue

Answer (score 1):

Answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3817882/3154984

Modules:
http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/product-updates-notifications.html
http://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/out-of-stock-notification-extension.html

On both module description I didn't see any thing related to new products notifications.